# How to get bash script to convert mp3 to wav using ffmpeg working?

Tags: bash, audio, ffmpeg, type-conversion

Every time I run this script it doesn't work. I get the output bash: command not found

I ran bash -x to see what was the problem but I don't understand the errors

```
bash -x mp3towav.sh 
+ for f in '*.mp3'
+ ffmpeg -i '' -acodec pcm_s16le -ac 1 -ar .wav
ffmpeg version 3.3 Copyright (c) 2000-2017 the FFmpeg developers
  built with Apple LLVM version 8.0.0 (clang-800.0.42.1)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/3.3 --enable-shared --enable-pthreads --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-hardcoded-tables --enable-avresample --cc=clang --host-cflags= --host-ldflags= --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libx264 --enable-libxvid --enable-opencl --disable-lzma --enable-vda
  libavutil      55. 58.100 / 55. 58.100
  libavcodec     57. 89.100 / 57. 89.100
  libavformat    57. 71.100 / 57. 71.100
  libavdevice    57.  6.100 / 57.  6.100
  libavfilter     6. 82.100 /  6. 82.100
  libavresample   3.  5.  0 /  3.  5.  0
  libswscale      4.  6.100 /  4.  6.100
  libswresample   2.  7.100 /  2.  7.100
  libpostproc    54.  5.100 / 54.  5.100
Trailing options were found on the commandline.
: No such file or directory
```

script is this

```
  1 #!/bin/bash
  2 for f in *.mp3; do ffmpeg -i "$file" -acodec pcm_s16le -ac 1 -ar "${file%.mp3}".wav;done
```

when running the corrected code provided I still get an error of:

```
ffmpeg version 3.3 Copyright (c) 2000-2017 the FFmpeg developers
  built with Apple LLVM version 8.0.0 (clang-800.0.42.1)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/3.3 --enable-shared --enable-pthreads --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-hardcoded-tables --enable-avresample --cc=clang --host-cflags= --host-ldflags= --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libx264 --enable-libxvid --enable-opencl --disable-lzma --enable-vda
  libavutil      55. 58.100 / 55. 58.100
  libavcodec     57. 89.100 / 57. 89.100
  libavformat    57. 71.100 / 57. 71.100
  libavdevice    57.  6.100 / 57.  6.100
  libavfilter     6. 82.100 /  6. 82.100
  libavresample   3.  5.  0 /  3.  5.  0
  libswscale      4.  6.100 /  4.  6.100
  libswresample   2.  7.100 /  2.  7.100
  libpostproc    54.  5.100 / 54.  5.100
Trailing options were found on the commandline.
Input #0, mp3, from 'hiraeth [ep].mp3':
  Duration: 00:23:39.36, start: 0.025057, bitrate: 128 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Audio: mp3, 44100 Hz, stereo, s16p, 128 kb/s
    Metadata:
      encoder         : LAME3.99r
    Side data:
      replaygain: track gain - -4.100000, track peak - unknown, album gain - unknown, album peak - unknown, 
At least one output file must be specified
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `for file in *.mp3; do ...`?  In the current code, you are using `file`, and not `f`, inside the loop.

Comment: And you must *not* quote `*.mp3`, or Bash tries to find a file called literally `*.mp3`.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is of course in the comment by codeforester:

```
#!/bin/bash
for file in *.mp3; do
   ffmpeg -i "$file" -acodec pcm_s16le -ac 1 -ar 44100 "${file%.mp3}".wav
done
```

(added 44100 per comment LordNeckbeard)
Some hints:

1) if you split your script over multiple lines, it becomes easier to spot errors like this.

2) Don't focus too much on the errors when running `bash -x`; it gives the on the output the commands. That what it is for. In this case:

```
+ ffmpeg -i '' -acodec pcm_s16le -ac 1 -ar .wav
```

The conclusion from this line is that ffmpeg is run with `''` as input file and `.wav` as output.

Comment: This gives me the an error saying I nee to specify my output file.

Comment: @ADASFA Your `-ar` is missing the value for the audio sample rate. Either remove `-ar`, and the output will attempt to use the same sample rate as the input, or add an appropriate value, such as `-ar 44100`.